# Are there any software tools for the Mythic system?

Tags: tools, mythic-rpg

I've tried to find some computerized tools for this system, but I did not manage to find any. The quite generic name is bringing back lots of not-related-to-the-game answers.

I would like to have at least a tool to avoid rolling on the fate table, so I could have a more seamless experience when using the system.

Answer (score 5):

You can find several html/javascript programs that automate the basics of the game if you join the Mythic_Role_Playing group on Yahoo Groups. Look in the Files section of the group. If you save web page, you don't need to be connected to the Internet to use it.

Answer (score 5):

I know two possibilities:

- Black Magic, javascript: http://www.evilgenius.org.nz/blackmagic.html
- RPG Solo, web-based: http://www.rpgsolo.com/

The RPG Solo one goes beyond Mythic and includes Instant Game for setting creation and Mark's Adventure Glyphs for visual inspiration, both optional. The basis system is also not vanilla Mythic but a slightly augmented version, such as adding "Yes/No, but/and..." answer types.

Black Magic being simple HTML+Javascript can be saved as a webpage to your computer and used offline. RPG Solo is a web-based application and can only be used online.

Comment: Thanks for this link: the RPGSolo is a real cool stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

This site has the Mythic GM Emulator done in flash: http://artifex0.50webs.com/GMEmulator.swf.

Answer (score 2):

I made an Etherpad Lite plugin for Mythic Game Emulator. You can collaborate with friends and have the game saved in the Internet.

It is at: http://mythic.herokuapp.com/

The plugin code can be found from: https://github.com/jrutila/ep_mythic

Comment: I got this to install but im having trouble getting any other plugins to install, if I can get spell check working this would be perfect, any help would be appreciated